# Wordpress custom setting return 10NULL

Tags: php, wordpress

I added custom field to wp_options.

field name is discount and value is 10 (varchar);

```
$discount = bloginfo('discount');
return var_dump($discount);
```

result is 10NULL;

I need convert to integer

Answer (score 1):

Try below one

```
$discount = (int) get_option('discount');
return var_dump($discount);
```

Comment: (int) can not help me

Comment: Why? and what is the reason to have var_dump?

Comment: I tried (int), and also $discount  = bloginfo('discount') * 1;
but result was same

Comment: result was that 10int(0)

Comment: so it is working and it's correct one? so always use get_option to have the value from option table

Answer (score 0):

The [`bloginfo`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/) is wrong in your context, they give information about the current site. If you need a value(s) from the options table `wp_options` you should use [`get_option`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/).

In your context the follow should work:

```
$discount = (int) get_option( 'discount' );
var_dump( $discount );
```

If the value if the field is really a integer (10), than you should add `(int)` to get a solid type integer.